# How to set other Python interpreter to IPython

Tags: python, ipython

Can we change the version of Python interpreter that IPython uses?

I know there is IPython and IPython3, but the problem is, IPython uses Python2.7, and IPython3 uses Python3.4.2, and I see no way to change that.

What if I wanted IPython to use which ever version of Python interpreter I wanted, could I make it that way?

I want IPython to use the newest Python version, Python3.6. Can I make it that way?

Comment: I have 3 environments set up on my pc, each having a different version of python. You can use Anaconda to make your life easier. It helps you switch between environments readily.

Comment: And how would that help me? Sry, I don't know Anaconda.

Comment: Don't you essentially need multiple versions of python? You can have 2 environments - one for python 3.4.2 and one for python 3.6. Install IPython on both of these environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I've found the solution.

You need to edit the file which starts IPython. On Linux you can enter it with: `sudo nano $(which ipython)`. 
Once you're inside the file change the shebang line to what ever Python interpreter you like. 
And directories that contain Python3.4 modules need to be added to $PYTHONPATH variable.

What is a shebang line?
First line in a file that represents the path to python interpreter that will be used.

Thanks to @code_byter.

Comment: Do tick this answer as the officially correct one to help the community. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Modifying a distributed file should be a last resort. I suggest this alternative using python3.6 on Ubuntu 17.04 as an example:

```
python3.6 -m pip install IPython # lots of output, make IPython available to script ipython3
python3.6 `which ipython3`
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 22 2017, 06:17:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170321] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, please check what version (by version I mean, the path of the interpreter) of python IPython uses using the `which ipython` command. Once you know the path, open the file and post the contents here.

Try to make it look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

The first line supposedly ensures that your local python interpreter is used. Commonly called a shebang line.

If you are on a Windows system, try the `where ipython` command instead.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to find the solution.

Comment: Anytime. Please post your solution so that it helps the rest of the community. :) Or tick this one, if its enough.

Comment: solution is here :)

Answer (score 1):

To me it was easier than I'd imagine. I did `vim /usr/bin/ipython3` and found the following Bash script:

```
#! /bin/sh

VERSION="3"

if [ ! -f /usr/bin/python$VERSION ]
then
[...]
```

To use Python version 3.6.2 I changed the `VERSION=3` line to `VERSION=3.6`. Please note that setting the `VERSION` variable to `3.6.2` did not work on my computer.